# Font face not supported in mobile browser

Tags: css

I followed [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/) guide to use the `@font-face` property for browser support, the method I used was "Slightly Deeper Browser Support". It is working on my machine (of course), I hosted the site and asked one of my friends to check the site to verify if the font is supported in his browser, and it is. However, when I checked the site from my iPhone using Safari one of the font is not supported and I wonder why that is. As mentioned in the guide I put the font face at the top, before any styles.

Here's the link to the hosted site https://gilbert1391.github.io/new-portfolio/

The fonts I want to support are The Bold Font (which is being used in the hero section) and Helvetica Neue, and the one that is not supported in my iphone's browser is the former one.

iPhone software version: 13.3.1

Comment: Make sure the font is uploaded in the right path, as of now its giving 404 error. https://gilbert1391.github.io/assets/fonts/theboldfont.woff2

Comment: Yes, the path was incorrect, now I am getting this warning Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:3000/src/assets/fonts/TheBoldFont.ttf

Comment: Is there a need to use `.ttf` font ? simply use `.woff2` font only and check the console for warning.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue

First, I had the font installed in my local machine and I thought the `@font-face` was working properly, I uninstalled the font from my computer and worked from there.

Second, I had path wrong, fixed that by using the following path:
`/src/assets/fonts/TheBoldFont.ttf`

But it still didn't work and I was getting this warning

```
Failed to decode downloaded font
```

What I did to fix it was to replace the previous path for this one:
`./assets/fonts/TheBoldFont.ttf`